# VaR historical stimulation for a stock portfolio without using a package in R

Tags: r, finance, stock

1. Suppose I have $100,000 to invest in a portfolio. How do I calculate the 95% 5-day VaR for this portfolio using historical simulations based on the past 501 daily returns?
2. Do the same thing but using simulations based on the linear model.

I know how to do them using the package but how could I solve these without using the package PerformanceAnalytics?

```r
#mean and covariance-variance of the monthly returns (without S&P500)
meann <- colMeans(r[,-31])
var.cov <- cov(r[,-31])

#Assume rf = 0.002 
Rf = 0.002
Rg <- meann - Rf

#Compute vector Z 
zg <- solve(var.cov) %*% Rg

#Compute the vector X
xg <- zg/sum(zg)

#Compute the returns and standard deviation of portfolio G
R_G <- t(xg) %*% t(r2[,-31])
sd_G <- (t(xg) %*% var.cov %*% xg)^0.5
```

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/07/calculating-var-with-r.html